# How have DNS recursion attacks happened?

Tags: penetration-test, dns

There are a few resources describing how to carry out DNS recursion attacks. Is there any good explanation to help me understand how these attacks work and if systems on my network are still vulnerable?

Comment: Wait, do you mean DNS cache poisoning?

Comment: What do you mean by "DNS recursion attacks"?  This is not a standard phrase that I've heard used in the field, so I suspect you've either heard it somewhere or made it up yourself.  (There are a variety of DNS attacks that might make use of recursion in some capacity, though I've never heard them called a "recursion attack".)  I can make some plausible guesses about what you might mean by that phrase, but I'd rather not guess.  What do *you* mean by "DNS recursion attacks"?  What makes you focus on "DNS recursion attacks"?

Answer (score 2):

The basic "Mother of all Recursion Attacks" was published by Dan Kaminsky.

The basic summary is that you ask for a site and provide an answer with the appropriate query idea for the recursive server before that server gets the real answer.

The best resource I've got for you is [An Illustrated Guide to the Kaminsky DNS Vulnerability](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-kaminsky-dns-vuln.html) which describes how the recursive system worked and why the flaw was possible.